# Replace occurrences on html file

Tags: awk, sed, html-parsing

I have to replace some kind of occurrences on thousands of html files and I'm intendind to use linux script for this.
Here are some examples of replaces I have to do

**From:** `<a class="wiki_link" href="/WebSphere+Application+Server">`

**To:** `<a class="wiki_link" href="/confluence/display/WIKIHAB1/WebSphere%20Application%20Server">`

That means, add /confluence/display/WIKIHAB1 as prefix and replace "+" by "%20".

I'll do the same for other tags, like img, iframe, and so on...

First, which tool should I use to make it? Sed? Awk? Other?

If anybody has any example, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out Beautiful Soup. It's a python library to parse html files, really easy to use and very well docummented.
I had no experience with Python and could wrote the code without problems.
Here is an example of python code to make the replace that I mentioned in the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Replaces plus sign(+) by %20 and add /confluence... prefix to each
#href parameter at anchor(a) tag that has wiki_link in class parameter
def fixAnchorTags(soup):
    tags = soup.find_all('a')

    for tag in tags:
        newhref = tag.get("href")

        if newhref is not None:
            if tag.get("class") is not None and "wiki_link" in tag.get("class"):
                newhref = newhref.replace("+", "%20")
                newhref = "/confluence/display/WIKIHAB1" + newhref
                tag['href'] = newhref

#Creates a folder to save the converted files                   
def setup():
    if not os.path.exists("converted"):
        os.makedirs("converted")

#Run all methods for each html file in the current folder
def run():
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            print "Converting " + file
            htmlfile = open(file, "r")
            converted = open("converted/"+file, "w")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, "html.parser")

            fixAnchorTags(soup)

            converted.write(soup.prettify("UTF-8"))
            converted.close()
            htmlfile.close()

setup()
run()
```